# Google Sheets: partially absolute cell reference

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sequence, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I would like an array of values to reference a cell (`D2` in the picture). Since I want this array to all have this value, I use an absolute cell reference.

The problem is, I want this pattern to be repeated later down in the sheet while referencing a corresponding placed, but different cell `D8`. But when I go to copy paste this array, it will still reference the old `D2` cell, and I have to update the cell reference manually.

Is there a way around this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following formula for creating your array in cell `A2`

```
=SEQUENCE(4,2,D2,0)
```

When you select `A2:B5` and copy/paste further down, the reference will update to

```
=SEQUENCE(4,2,D8,0)
```

[image]

Read more about **[SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I simplified my description somewhat. Instead of containing just the value of the target cells in column D, they contain a somewhat complicated formula that refers to them (as well as other cells). Am I just out of luck, in that situation?

Comment: *"Unfortunately I simplified my description **somewhat**"* Quite an understatement, don't you think? :)  hehehe. In any case. One would need to know the actual formula so as to give you a more definite answer. The way I read your image is *"In cell `A2` I place `=$D$2` and drag till `B5`"*. If not, then how do you get the rest of the values to `B5`? It would definitely help if you were willing to share a test sheet. Also, a script may be able to achieve what you need. I will leave my answer here though, since I believe it can help others.

Comment: Heh, yeah, sorry. Your answer def. helped, though. I ended up using the array brackets ({}), which let me do something similar to the above, but with text. In combination with the INDIRECT command, this let me achieve what I wanted. I will leave this up, as this more simple example may be more useful to posterity.

Comment: Glad I could help. It would be interesting to see the solution applied to your final formula. Just a thought.